# Linq statement not bringinb back expected results

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 Index View.  It has multiple partial Views.  One of the partial views has a Jquery DataGrid Table, and below the table the user can select random supplies to add to their supply order.  When they select a supply from, and click submit, I use an Ajax.BeginForm call that only refreshes that particular partial view (including the datagrid table), and not the entire page.

This works.  When I add a supply and click submit.  The partial view refreshes and it shows the newly requested supply in the DataGrid Table, as expected.  Each supply is given a Requisition Number that will tie it to the header information of the table.  That way, users can order multiple supplies within one order.

Here is where I begin to get lost.  I need the DataGrid Table to only show supplies associated to the current Requisition Number.

The Requisition Number is created by a random generator and stored as TempData value, with TempData.Keep() so that I can use it multiple times during the order process. (There are probably better ways, but this is pretty new to me and I am just chugging along for now).

```
//Auto Generate Requisition Number
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string str = guid.ToString();
ViewBag.TransNum = str;
TempData["ReqNo"] = str;
TempData.Keep();
```

The above code is from my Index Controller.  My Index view contains my other partial Views.  So, I generate my Requistion Number and save it as TempData to be used in the other partial views.  Because the index does not refresh, and so the number will not change until order is complete and a new order is created.

My AddSupplies Partial View contains both the datagrid table and the post form

```
@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Orders>
@{
Layout = null;
}
<div id="divSupplies">
<h3>Monthly Requisition: Supplies and Forms</h3>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
<div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Requested Supplies</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<table id="supplies-data-table"
class="table table-striped table-bordered"
style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Line ID</th>
<th>Requisition Number</th>
<th>Supplies ID</th>
<th>Amount Ordered</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var asset in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>@asset.LineID</td>
<td>@asset.RequisitionNumber</td>
<td>@asset.SuppliesID</td>
<td>@asset.UnitsOrdered</td>
</tr>                           }
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<!-- Select Supplies-->

<h4>Request Supplies</h4>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddSupplies", "ICSNewOrders", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divSupplies" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="form-group">

@Html.Label("Supplies Requested:", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownList("SuppliesList", null, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

</div>

<!-- End Supplies-->


<!-- Begin Supply Location-->

<div class="form-group">
 @Html.Label("Supply Location:", new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.TextBox("Location", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.SupplyLocation, @readonly = "readonly" })
    </div>

<!-- End Supply Location-->

<!-- Begin Units OnHand-->

<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("Units OnHand:", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("OnHand", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.OnHand, @readonly = "readonly" })
 </div>

<!-- End Units OnHand-->

<!-- Begin Units Ordered-->

@Html.Label("Qty of Units Ordered:", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("HowMany", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "HowMany" })


<!-- End Units Ordered-->

<!-- Begin RequisitionNumber-->

<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label("RequisitionNumber:", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("RequisitionNumber", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "RequisitionNumber", Value = ViewBag.TransNum, @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="submit" value="Add Supply To Request" class="btn btn-default" id="addsupply" />

<!-- End RequisitionNumber OnHand-->

 <hr />
}

</div>
 <!-- Add Java Script-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#supplies-data-table').DataTable();
 });
</script>
```

User selects supply and how many they want, and submit button posts to ICS_Orders table and refreshes the partial view, including datagird table.

In my POST AddSupplies controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddSupplies([Bind(Include = "LineID, RequisitionNumber, SuppliesID, UnitsOrdered, UnitsDelivered")] ICS_Orders iCS_Orders, int? id)
{
try
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
// create TempData and store as Viewbag for partial views
ViewBag.TransNum = TempData["ReqNo"];
TempData.Keep();// To be able to reuse TempData Variable multiple times

// Create TempData var for linq                    
var currReq = (string)TempData["ReqNo"];


// ICS_Orders
var q = db.ICS_Orders;

//Select Orders where Requistion numbe = TempData
var w = db.ICS_Orders.Where(s => s.RequisitionNumber == currReq);

return View(w);
}

return PartialView("AddSupplies");
```

Here is where I am confused.   If I return View(q) it works.  I see the recent added record in the table.  BUT, I also see ALL the records.  Even those not associated to the proper Requisition Number.

When I return View(w) - I get an empty table.  Yet, when I run in debug, and use stops for checking. I can hover over w and see that the currReq is the correct Requisition Number from the TempData . . .so why is it not bringing back the matching results?

Sorry for all the code.  Just wanted to make sure everything was clear and visible.

Comment: Can you post your code for writing the ICS_Orders record to the database?  If you look at the data in the database, do the records have the correct Requisition Number?

Comment: @paul - I feel like such an idiot.  Somehow, during all of the trial and error, I had removed the actual save command  db.ICS_Orders.Add(iCS_Orders);db.SaveChanges();   After adding them back in, it seems to be working now.  I am getting only the related Req numbers.  Oddly enough. . somehow I was saving data to the ICS_Orders table even tho .  . It's been a long day.  I need to go home and have a drink.  Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem, it's frequently the little things that can trip you up the most, and just having a fresh set of eyes on the problem can save hours of troubleshooting.